# Validar coordenadas geográficas

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Como posso validar uma coordenada geográfica para saber se realmente corresponde a uma localização válida? Por exemplo, -47.888477, -100.555444; Essas coordenadas eu não peguei em nenhum mapa, são números aleatórios que me vieram na cabeça agora para usar de exemplo, como faço para saber se é uma coordenada válida?

Comment: O que você considera uma coordenada válida?

Comment: Por exemplo, -47.888477, -220.555444 me parece ser inválida pois pelo que vi fuçando o google-map, não existe longitude que chegue a -220. Preciso exatamente saber o que são coordenadas válidas para que eu possa criar um algoritmo para validar.
Eu posso validar a quantidade de caracteres digitados mas para validar se os números passados correspondem a uma coordenada válida, preciso saber exatamente isso, quais as características de uma coordenada válida, preciso saber coisas como, latitude pode ir de **-X** a **X positivo**, longitude de **-X** a **X positivo** etc.

Comment: Matheus,em uma situação normal no cotidiano, qual seria a necessidade dessa validação? Levando em conta que não é viável pedir para um usuário digitar as suas coordenadas em uma área de texto.

Comment: Não será! As coordenadas virão de dispositivos rodando apps integrados ao google map api, mas eu quero ter alguma validação na minha aplicação, mesmo sabendo que as chances dos apps enviarem uma coordenada inválida seja muito pequena.
O app mobile pegará a coordenada do local e enviará via web service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Google utiliza o sistema de coordenadas WGS84 standard. Para validar poderá considerar estes valores aproximados:

Latitude : max/min +90 até -90

Longitude : max/min +180 até -180

Comment: Isso vai depender do sistemas de coordenas que estás usando (UTM, Graus, minutos e segundos,...)

Answer (score -2):

Eu uso a lib "validator"

Instale: `npm i validator`

Importe no seu projeto

```
const validator = require("validator");

const lat = validator.isLatLong(seu_objeto ou variavel)

static ValidationPolygonControllerLocation = (long, lat) => {

    if (long < -180 || long > 180) throw { message: "Invalid longitude [controller_location]. Must be between -180 and 180"}

    if (lat < -90 || lat > 90) throw { message: "Invalid latitude [controller_location]. Must be between -90 and 90"}

};
```